# SignalR- How to Remove Clients from hub in signalR using Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am planning to implementing signalR (angular + .net core) in my project, currently facing an issue, while adding new clients the process memory is increasing and whenever client is disconnected from hub the memory is not reducing. Is it possible to remove a client from signalR hub? (angular) so that the memory size will be reduce or any other approach to handle this issue?. Also please suggest any issues will occur while integrate signalR in the project.

Comment: According to your description, Angular should be the client and the asp.net core project should be the server. And you mentioned that `client is disconnected from hub the memory is not reducing`, I'm afraid you may wait for a while and then check if the memory reduced. This is because the configuration for `ClientTimeoutInterval`, you may check [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options).